# Eclipse: Import+Export actions in "Save Actions" option

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

It is possible to Import+Export Clean Up setting as xml file at `Preferences->Java->Code Style->Clean Up`.

I want these setting to be applied on the code each time I save a file.

Unfortunately, when I go to `Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions` I don't have an option to Import+Export Clean Up settings (even though I have the option to configure them manually).
Is there a way to Import+Export these settings?

Clarification: My goal is to create Clean Up setting xml that I can share with my team members so that if any of us saves a file these Clean Up settings will be automatically applied on the code.

I am using Eclipse 4.3 Kepler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These settings are included in the Export Preferences but only when you specify 'Export all'.

There does not seem to be any export that just exports these settings.

The settings are stored in the workspace in the file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` but again they are mixed in with lots of other settings.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to manually edit the exported .epf file and erase all irrelevant preferences? Of course in a way that it will still be valid for import.

Comment: All the lines seem to start with `/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/sp_cleanup.`. The epf file is a Java properties file so is fairly safe to edit.

Comment: using only the lines that start with that prefix, when I try to import I see in the Description: `Empty list.
Note: Not all preferences support individual import`. The import has no effect.

Comment: Possibly the `@org.eclipse.jdt.ui=3.9.50.v20140317-1811` entry is somthing to do with this - but without researching the source code I am just guessing

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the old "**.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs**" workspace file.
2. Copy all "**sp_cleanup.***" properties from the old workspace file and paste into the new one (replacing the old same properties).

Comment: To activate the save actions option, you'll have to update the propery `editor_save_participant_org.eclipse.jdt.ui.postsavelistener.cleanup` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran some diffs with the generated preferences file (.epf) and identified the specific entries that need to be added to your preferences file to enable Post Save Actions

They are as follows (Tested in Eclipse Mars.1):

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/sp_cleanup.format_source_code=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/sp_cleanup.organize_imports=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/editor_save_participant_org.eclipse.jdt.ui.postsavelistener.cleanup=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/sp_cleanup.on_save_use_additional_actions=false
```

They will translate into:
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions

- Perform the selected actions on save (checked)
- Format source code (checked)
- Format edited lines (unchecked)
- Organize imports (checked)
- Additional Actions (unchecked)